# Installing Jasper WAR file -- Missing dependencies?

Tags: maven, ant, installation, jasperserver

When I run the command: **js-ant import-minimal-ce** I get an exception error:

```
[java] Resource name: applicationContext-virtual-data-source.xml
```

Followed by:

> [java] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'executionOwnerVoter': Injection of
>   resouorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'executionOwnerVoter': Injection of resource
>   dependencies failed; nested exception

I can only best determine I am somehow missing a dependency (perhaps that of Hibernate.jar?) as this appears to occur when performing database operations.

Any ideas? Frustrated and out of options...

Alex

Comment: post more of stacktrace

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ta7wnCfT

Comment: I should note I opened the same issue on the JasperBoards: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/841550/js-ant-import-minimal-ce-fails...not sure if this adds anything here or not?